Similar convergence of GMRES and CG for SPD matrix
Consider the $100 \times 100$ tridiagonal SPD matrix
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    -6 & 1 &  & \dotsm & \\
    1 & -6 & 1 & \dotsm &\\
    \vdots &1 & \ddots &\ddots& \vdots\\
    &&\ddots&&1\\
    & \dotsm &&1&-6
\end{bmatrix}$
and the vector
$b=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 & 2 &\cdots & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}^T\in\mathbb{C}^{100}$
If $A=VDV^{-1}$ is the eigen decomposition of A and we can enclose all eigenvalues of A in a disk with radius $r$ and center $c$ we get an upper bound of the residual norm for GMRES as $$\frac{||Ax_m-b||_2}{||b||_2}\leq||V||_2\ ||V^{-1}||_2 \left(\frac{r}{|c|}\right)^m = \textrm{cond}(V)\cdot \left(\frac{r}{|c|}\right)^m$$
Similarly, the upper bound of CG is given by
$$
\frac{||Ax_m-b||_{A^{-1}}}{||b||_{A^{-1}}}\leq2\left(\frac{\sqrt{\kappa(A)}-1}{\sqrt{\kappa(A)}+1}\right)^m
$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$
\frac{||Ax_m-b||_{2}}{||b||_{2}}\leq2\sqrt{\kappa(A)}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\kappa(A)}-1}{\sqrt{\kappa(A)}+1}\right)^m
$$
where $\textrm{cond}(A)=\kappa(A)$
Implementing GMRES and CG for 30 iterations, I get the following plot.

I would assume that in raw time, CG converges faster than GMRES and is also more memory efficient. But I can not explain why GMRES converges as fast as CG per iteration for this problem from a theoretical standpoint. Does anyone have any explanation for this?
Thank you in advance for any help!
